# Center one or both axis to center the "view" around a specific plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

Let's say the **point (10, 50)** divides my plot of a 2d coordinate system in four sections:

- top left, top right
- bottom left, bottom right

This point is fixed and I know its location in advance.

Task: Always keep this point in the middle of the by matplotlib displayed coordinate system.

Sure I can achieve this by for example setting

```py
axs.set_xlim(0, 20)
axs.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

This perfectly centers mentioned point in the middle of the graph. The problem with this approach is, that I do not know in advance about my dynamic scatter data that I also want to visualize within this plot.

Sometimes it might be

```py
x_data = (2, 5, 15)
y_data = (25, 30, 75)
```

This would work with my previously set `xlim` and `ylim` but sometimes the data might be:

```py
x_data = (-10, 0, 20)
y_data = (-2, 101, 205)
```

This data would not show up because it is outside of set `xlim` and `ylim`.

**Question:** Can I keep the default dynamic expanding of the axis so every point of my data is included and still somehow center the point in "the middle" of the graph?

Different phrasing: Can I specify the center of an axis without specifying its min and max and still keep the auto scaling so "every point" that is to scatter is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [an OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76380541/center-one-or-both-matplotlib-axis-to-center-the-view-around-a-specific-plot/76382853#comment134687942_76381795)

> My question was more: "Can I center the axis without specifying xlim and ylim?"

No.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like (for x axis):

```py
if x_data:
    left_span, right_span = center_x - min(x_data), max(x_data) - center_x
    half_x_span = max(left_span, right_span)
    if half_x_span > 0:
        axs.set_xlim(center_x - half_x_span, center_x + half_x_span)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I already have a solution up and running where I adjust the `ylim` and `xlim` accordingly. My question was more: "Can I center the axis **without** specifying `xlim` and `ylim`?"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Smin                       Smax
  |---+---------------|----------+-------|
 C-L                 C                  C+L
```

From the previous figure, we have

```
C+L ≥ Smax ⇒ L ≥ Smax-C
Smin ≥ C-L ⇒ L ≥ C-Smin
```

and finally

```
L = max(Smax-C, C-Smin)
```

Translated into the context of Matplotlib

```
def limits(c, mnmx):
    mn, mx = mnmx
    L = max(mx-c, c-mn)
    return(c-L, c+L)

xc, yc = 10, 50
# plot your data
ax.set_xlim(limits(xc, ax.get_xlim())
ax.set_ylim(limits(yc, ax.get_ylim())
```

---

An example follows

[image]

```
In [22]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [23]: def limits(c, mnmx):
    ...:     mn, mx = mnmx
    ...:     L = max(mx-c, c-mn)
    ...:     return (c-L, c+L)

In [24]: def plot_example (ax, xmn_xmx):
    ...:     y = [50, 50]
    ...:     ax.scatter(xmn_xmx, y)
    ...:     ax.scatter(10, 50)
    ...:     ax.set_xlim(limits(10, ax.get_xlim()))

In [25]: fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(6, 6), layout='constrained')
    ...: for ax, xmn_xmx in zip(axes, ((-3, -2), (12, 15), (-20, 100))):
    ...:     plot_example(ax, xmn_xmx)
    ...: plt.show()
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I already have a solution up and running where I adjust the `ylim` and `xlim` accordingly. My question was more: "Can I center the axis **without** specifying `xlim` and `ylim`?"

Comment: @Tarquinius The solution I propose ***automatically*** and ***correctly*** sets the limits for the axes. Further, I don't know how one could change the limits of an axis, not using `.set_*lim((..., ...,))` in the context of Matplotlib.

Comment: I agree, your solution is equally good to Roman Pavelka and my already working solution. The question is not about "how one could change the limits of an axis", the question is about how one can force a value being the center of the axis regardless of its limits and scale. But yes, maybe there is no solution to this in matplotlib.

Comment: For example this would not work when you turn the axis to a logarithmic scale. The math of figuring out the xlim and ylim obviously is different then. I thought there is something like in plotly where you can set the viewport on the graph regardless where the data is.

Comment: 1. Your original question doesn't mention a logarithmic axis, it is however very simple to extend my approach to a logarithmic axis, but this is left as an exercise for the OP. 2. Your original question doesn't frame the problem in terms of "viewport"s but, again, it's very easy  to set a viewport using, what else?, `ax.set_?lim((..., ...))`. ፨፨፨፨፨፨፨፨ Try to explain to yourself the reason why you avert the usage of`ax.set_?lim((..., ...))` because I quit, Goodbye.